# Setting Background image for Navigation Bar With a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiimage

Sir i need to set the background Image at my Navigation Bar I have tried the sollutions over here,I am unable to get it. Please guide me

```
-(void)edditingNavigationBar{
UIImageView *titleView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(138, 20, 35, 29)];
[titleView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addVehicle"]];
titleView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.navigationItem.titleView=titleView;

if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"head_bg"]  ;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];}
}
```

this is how it looks now.

[image]

and when I resize the image acording to the height and width of navigation Bar that is 320*44 it looks like this

[image]

this is the actual image
[image]

Comment: what is this + sign image?

Comment: why you need to resize the image? it will manage it self.

Comment: @SaadChaudhry its the logo which i place at the place of title view .You have seen my code? so where am I getting wrong sir.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Comment: anybody else want to guide like Saad sir  ?

Comment: harshit problem is with your assets get the proper sized images and you are done.

Comment: @SaadChaudhry thanks can u help me with the sizes